# Counting the number of iteration in a loop

Tags: python, loops

I cannot get the correct number of the iterations for each steps. Is there any way to solve this problem?

The output for this code is [(5, 1), (8, 2)], which should be [(5, 100), (8, 63)]

Comment: Hi! The indentation of your code is a bit strange, maybe some parts are missing? Would be nice for me when debugging your code to have a working example:)

Comment: There is no code here, it isn't clear what you are asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you use len(step) as your increment in your for loop, python is using 2 as the step increment, since the step list contains 2 items.  What you want is to run your loop once for each step interval present in your step list.

```
step=[5,8]
lst= []

for s in step:
    counter = 0
    for i in range(0, 500, s):
        counter += 1
    lst.append(counter)

output=list(zip(step,lst))
print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it this way:

```py
step=[5,8]
lst= []
counter = 0
for x in step:
    for i in range(0, 500, x):
        counter += 1
    lst.append(counter)
print(lst)
output=list(zip(step,lst))
print(output)
```